# Doctrine join query to get all record satisfies count greater than 1

Tags: doctrine-orm, createquery

I tried with normal sql query

```
SELECT activity_shares.id FROM `activity_shares` 
INNER JOIN (SELECT `activity_id` FROM `activity_shares`
GROUP BY `activity_id`
HAVING  COUNT(`activity_id`) > 1 ) dup ON activity_shares.activity_id = dup.activity_id
```

Which gives me record id say **10** and **11**

But same query I tried to do in `Doctrine query builder`,

```
 $qb3=$this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('c')
           ->add('select','c.id')
           ->add('from','MyBundleDataBundle:ActivityShare c')
           ->innerJoin('c.activity', 'ca')
         //  ->andWhere('ca.id = c.activity')
           ->groupBy('ca.id')
          ->having('count(ca.id)>1');
```

**Edited:**

```
        $query3=$qb3->getQuery();
        $query3->getResult();
```

Generated SQL is:

```
SELECT a0_.id AS id0 FROM activity_shares a0_ 
INNER JOIN activities a1_ ON a0_.activity_id = a1_.id 
GROUP BY a1_.id HAVING count(a1_.id) > 1
```

Gives only 1 record that is **10**.I want to get both.I'm not getting idea where I went wrong.Any idea?

My tables structure is:

```
ActivityShare
    +-----+---------+-----+---
    | Id  |activity |Share| etc...
    +-----+---------+-----+----
    | 1   | 1       |1    |
    +-----+---------+-----+---
    | 2   | 1       | 2   |
    +-----+---------+-----+---
```

`Activity` is foreign key to `Activity` table.
I want to get Id's 1 and 2

Comment: What are you executing to get the result?

Comment: You must have a line like `$query->getResult()` to retrieve the entities. If you have something `$query->getSingleResult()` you'll only get one row.

Comment: I have edited question.Please refer.

Comment: That is looking good. Try `$query3->getSql()` to get the SQL string and execute that directly to your database using a MySql client. See if you are getting the same result.

Comment: ya.It is giving only on record.Result I'm getting proper Id of one record .But I want both records Id.The above normal sql query I tried in MySql client.It was giving me two records Id.

Comment: SQL string I'm getting is `SELECT a0_.id AS id0 FROM activity_shares a0_ INNER JOIN activities a1_ ON a0_.activity_id = a1_.id GROUP BY a1_.id HAVING count(a1_.id) > 1`

Comment: You mean you are getting different results executing the SQL string generated by Doctrine? If so spot the differences in the SQL or put the generated SQL in your question.

Comment: Clearly your generated SQL doesn't contain the subquery which is in your manually typed SQL. I don't know how to do this with the queryBuilder. I'd suggest you to google `doctrine queryBuilder subquery`, or wait for someone who nows the queryBuilder by heart.

Comment: Okay.Thank you for your precious time:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.I finally managed to get answer

My Doctrine query is:

```
$subquery=$this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('as')
      ->add('select','a.id')
      ->add('from','MyBundleDataBundle:ActivityShare as')
      ->innerJoin('as.activity', 'a')
      ->groupBy('a.id')
      ->having('count(a.id)>1');



 $query=$this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('c')
      ->add('select','c.id')
      ->add('from','ChowzterDataBundle:ActivityShare c')
      ->innerJoin('c.activity', 'ca');

    $query->andWhere($query->expr()->in('ca.id', $subquery->getDql()))
      ;

    $result = $query->getQuery();
    print_r($result->getResult());
```

And SQL looks like:

```
SELECT a0_.id AS id0 FROM activity_shares a0_ INNER JOIN activities a1_ ON a0_.activity_id = a1_.id WHERE a1_.id IN (SELECT a2_.id FROM activity_shares a3_ INNER JOIN activities a2_ ON a3_.activity_id = a2_.id GROUP BY a2_.id HAVING count(a2_.id) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Simplified SQL

first of all let me simplify that query so it gives the same result :

```
SELECT id FROM `activity_shares` 
GROUP BY `id`
HAVING  COUNT(`activity_id`) > 1
```

## Docrtrine QueryBuilder

### If you store the id of the activty in the table like you sql suggests:

You can use the simplified SQL to build a query:

```
$results =$this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('c')
           ->add('select','c.id')
           ->add('from','MyBundleDataBundle:ActivityShare c')
           ->groupBy('c.id')
           ->having('count(c.activity)>1');
           ->getResult();
```

### If you are using association tables ( Doctrine logic)

here you will have to use join but the count may be tricky

**Solution 1**

use the associative table like an entitiy ( as i see it you only need the id)
Let's say the table name is activityshare_activity

it will have two fields activity_id and activityshare_id, if you find a way to add a new column id to that table and make it Autoincrement + Primary the rest is easy :

the new entity being called **ActivityShareActivity**

```
$results =$this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('c')
           ->add('select','c.activityshare_id')
           ->add('from','MyBundleDataBundle:ActivityShareActivity c')
           ->groupBy('c.activityshare_id')
           ->having('count(c.activity_id)>1');
           ->getResult();
```

the steps to add the new identification column to make it compatible with doctrine (you need to do this once):

1. add the column (INT , NOT NULL) **don' t put the autoincrement yet**

   ALTER TABLE tableName ADD id INT NOT NULL
2. Populate the column using a php loop like for
3. Modify the column to be autoincrement

   ALTER TABLE tableName MODIFY id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

**Solution2**

The correction to your query

```
$result=$this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
           ->select('c.id')
           ->from('MyBundleDataBundle:ActivityShare', 'c')
           ->innerJoin('c.activity', 'ca')
           ->groupBy('c.id') //note: it's c.id not ca.id
           ->having('count(ca.id)>1')
           ->getResult();
```

I posted this one last  because i am not 100% sure of the output of having+ count but it should word just fine :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Your simplified query will give only one record Id.Say there are two records with Id 1 and 2 which satisfies condition count>1.It will give me only first record Id 1.I want both.And I guess `groupBy` should be on activity_id not activity_share tables Id.